# how to include a semicolon in sql query VALUES?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have this php script that generate an sql query. However, it needs a semicolon inside the sql statement and because of that, the sql query doesn't work.

```
VALUES ('Installed Modules', 'MODULE_BOXES_INSTALLED', 'bm_shopping_cart.php;bm_categories.php', 'This is automatically updated. No need to edit.', '6', '0', now())
```

It is included in this function.

```
function insert_configuration6_table($table_name9, $type) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (!empty ($wpdb->charset))
        $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset}";
    if (!empty ($wpdb->collate))
        $charset_collate .= " COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table_name9} (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) VALUES ('Installed Modules', 'MODULE_BOXES_INSTALLED', 'bm_shopping_cart.php;bm_categories.php', 'This is automatically updated. No need to edit.', '6', '0', now()),('Installed Template Block Groups', 'TEMPLATE_BLOCK_GROUPS', 'boxes', 'This is automatically updated. No need to edit.', '6', '0', now());";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

I have searched a lot for this however, I can't find a solution that work.

How can I make an sql query that includes a semicolon(;) in the values?

Thanks.

Comment: Mysql input can be escaped with a preceding `\\`. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you are talking about the semicolon inside the string then it won't cause a problem, therefore your problem resides in something else. Can you provide the mysql error, please?

Comment: @Ken First test without ";" and if it works then you'll know for sure this is the problem. If it still doesn't work, then the problem lies elsewhere. It may not be relevant to your simple example, but in general case you should consider using bound parameters to avoid problems with escaping characters and fortify against SQL injection.

Comment: The problem is that, the value **bm_shopping_cart.php;bm_categories.php** doesn't stored in the database that suppose to be inserted by that query. When I removed **;bm_categories.php** the value **bm_shopping_cart.php** is inserted on the database. So the problem resides on having the semicolon. I also tried using \ but the problem still there. I really need the semicolon included on the value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The SQL Statement/syntax seems wrong. You should only have one bracket set for Values, instead you have two separated by comma. Shouldn't it be as follows?</strike>

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table_name9} (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) VALUES ('Installed Modules', 'MODULE_BOXES_INSTALLED', 'bm_shopping_cart.php;bm_categories.php', 'This is automatically updated. No need to edit.', '6', '0', now());";
```

Never mind, that was incorrect. I also think that there shouldn't be any problem with a semicolon in a SQL query; what's the actual error that you are getting?

Comment: This appears to be a MySQL idiosyncracy. This is valid under MySQL: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`.

Comment: The problem is that, the value **bm_shopping_cart.php;bm_categories.php** doesn't stored in the database that suppose to be inserted by that query. When I removed **;bm_categories.php** the value **bm_shopping_cart.php** is inserted on the database. So the problem resides on having the semicolon. I also tried using \ but the problem still there. I really need the semicolon included on the value.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem seems to be with using semicolons with dbDelta, not so much because of SQL. See this question as well, it suggests a fix that may work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062621/wordpress-dbdelta-function-fails-to-execute-my-query

Answer (score 1):

As I landed here from Google, I'll add my solution even if this is very old question.

For a simple way of using semicolons or whatever other special characters in php sql query one can encode the string.

In php encode string first

```
base64_encode($value)
```

Then in the query use for example

```
UPDATE ... SET value = FROM_BASE64({$value}) ...
```

The reverse would be to use base64_dedode and TO_BASE64()